# Setting mobile brightness to match room light causes eye sight?

Tags: eye, eye-strain

My son is watching mobile for many hours. I am not able to stop him as I am also working. He dont have any friends atleast to spend outside.

I just check his mobile and adjusts the briggtness to match room brightness.

Will that be enough to protect his eyes? or it causes eye problems whatever we do if we watch mobile long hours because of blue light?